# Change Color of Selected Action in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

When I click on one of these actions, I want to change the color of the selected button:
[image]

JS:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class Demo extends LightningElement {

columns=[];
recordsDisplayed = [{"Id":'111',"Name":"name1","Phone":"01234567"}, {"Id":'222',"Name":"name2","Phone":"4567890"}];

connectedCallback() {
    this.columns = [
        { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name'},
        { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone'}
    ];

    //more columns here...

    this.columns.push({ type: 'button-icon', typeAttributes: { 
        iconName: 'action:preview', name: 'preview', alternativeText: 'Preview Record', class: { fieldName: `format` } } 
    });
}

handleRowAction(event) {
    if (event.detail.action.name === 'preview') {
        //color the button that was clicked
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
<lightning-datatable key-field="id" 
                     data-id='datatable'
                     data={recordsDisplayed} 
                     columns={columns} 
                     onrowaction={handleRowAction}>
</lightning-datatable>
```

Comment: Have you considered using the `variant` for [lightning-button-icon](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button-icon/example) here?

Comment: [lightning-button-icon-stateful](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button-icon-stateful/example) sounds perfect for this use case, it changes color on selection out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the row's attribute to change just one button.

Your typeAttributes needs to be changed to:

```
 iconName: 'action:preview', name: 'preview', alternativeText: 'Preview Record', variant: { fieldName: `format` } }
```

To get there properly, first find the element:

```
let actionRow = this.recordsDisplayed[this.recordsDisplayed.indexOf(event.detail.row)];
```

... or ...

```
let actionRow => this.recordsDisplayed.find(row => event.detail.row.Id === row.Id);
```

Then set the value for the field you mapped for the variant:

```
actionRow.format = 'brand';
```

Finally, make sure you set `@track` on `recordsDisplayed`, or copy the array so that LWC can determine a change needs to be rendered:

```
@track displayedRecords;
```

... or ...

```
this.displayedRecords = [...this.displayedRecords];
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
handleRowAction(event) {
  if(event.detail.action === 'preview') {
    let actionRow = this.displayedRows.find(
      (row) => row.Id === event.detail.row.Id
    );
    actionRow.format = 'brand';
    this.displayedRows = [...this.displayedRows];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for the detailed answer.